# How to create dynamic variables in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my Code:

```
function NewPerson() {
    var count = parseInt($('#HiddenField').html());
    count++;
    $('#HiddenField').html(count);
    Var dynamicVariable = 'Person'+'Count' 
}
```

I want to define variable on this line `Var **dynamicVariable** = 'Person'+'Count'`

Now I need to create variable with count number

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript

Comment: Are you trying to append the variable `count`? Then, use this `var dynamicVariable = 'Person' + count;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use dynamic variable names in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript)

Comment: thsi is not duplicate , I cant use this answer 
[link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript

Comment: dont understand your question. can you elaborate more? like what is that you want to achieve? expected outcome, etc

Comment: i want Create variable whit Count number,
i want genrerate this code:
var 1=value;
var 2= value;var 3= value;var 4= value; ......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also try this.

```
  var count = 1; //Let this be your count variable.
  var PersonString = "Person" + count; //Building a dynamic name for your variable
  alert(PersonString); //Person1 will be alerted
  window[PersonString] = "One";
  alert(Person1); //One will be alerted.
```

Click [here](https://jsfiddle.net/53kff99p/1/) for the fiddle.

> **P.S** : Here variables created dynamically will have a global scope.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, the design pattern in this scenario is to use an object.

```
//These are your variables
var myVar1 = '1';
var myVar2 = '2';

//The object holding all your dynamic variables
var MyVarObj = {};


//Create dynamic variables (object properties)
MyVarObj[myVar1] = 'value1'
MyVarObj[myVar2] = 'value2'


console.log(MyVarObj);   // {1: 'value1', 2: 'value2'}
```